# What does having "< >" around a pointer mean/do? C++

Tags: c++

I have my little code that needs to be solved/fixed but I'm struggling and getting stuck on problems too simple to be found with a simple Google search.

```cpp
int vector, Shape, Shapes;
int Parameters;

int main()
{
    string UserCommand;
    vector <Shape*> Shapes;
    vector <string> Parameters;
}
```

My question is what basically the `<>` around the pointer are for? What do they do? They give me the following error on `<Shape*>`:

> expected an expression

Is something meant to follow this pointer?

Also, where `vector <string> Parameters;` is, I get the error:

> type name not allowed

It's something to do with the `<>` symbols again.

What does one do when something is surrounded by `<>`?

Comment: It's a template parameter. `vector <Shape*>` holds a vector of `Shape*` and `vector <string>` holds a vector of `string`.

Comment: where is the sense in declaring `vector, Shape, Shapes, Parameters` as integers and then using them like types or in more declaration statements

Comment: `int vector` Blessed is the name of the standard library templates (or at least they should be).

Comment: You have naming conflicts between your `vector` variable and the standard `std::vector` container, and between your `Shape` variable and `Shape` struct/class.

Comment: Normally it's written without a space, like this: `vector<Shape*> Shapes;`. This declares a variable `Shapes` as a list (so-called [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) of `Shape *`. You'll need to remove or rename `int vector`, as it interfers with the standard `vector`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat whitespace doesn't matter in this case

Comment: You do `using std::string;` and not `using namespace std;`, right? Create a [mcve] and someone will be able to give a definite answer quickly.

Comment: "getting stuck on problems too simple to be found with a simple Google search." and that's why you need a good C++ book or course and start learning C++ the proper way.

Comment: Please read what a vector is...

Comment: @bolov usually the reason we cannot find something on google is because it is too complex, I never imagined that we would need to such something so simple, like how to open a door. If you wanted a more complex definition you can do: while not at the door, walk towards door, when reached door, grab handle, and rotate 180 degrees, and then pull.

Comment: [Sometimes you have to push](https://i.imgur.com/0BrTj5X.jpg)

Comment: You have 2 declarations of "Shapes", once statically, at the top of your program, once in your main function. You should rename one of them.

Comment: @fstam all of the `int` variables in global scope are in conflict with the variables in `main()` and should either be renamed or eliminated altogether.

Comment: @user4581301 well usually I can find what I am looking for on google, by typing out the error from my compiler or the assignment... Like once I wanted to implement BST, I just typed in Binary Search Tree implementation took less than 30 seconds to find what I was looking for so yep...

Comment: @Scheff undo and redo?? Are you talking about word, powerpoint, Excel, Access, some other MS application, or C++??

Comment: @Scheff even I am confused what you are talking about how do you expect google to know about it??

Comment: @YunfeiChen This was a "story of old" that googling something is not always easy. My intention was to find something about how to implement Undo/Redo in my own application. However, instead of code samples or concepts, I found (I believe) every manual of every existing application mentioning Undo/Redo commands of that. Whatever I tried (by modifying my search pattern), the result was always the same (until I gave up finally). -- A story of old. Please, forget about it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

FOUND THE ISSUE. I simply created another header and cpp file, then deleted them both and visual studio woke up and removed the error. Weird

Comment: This does **not** answer the posted question _"What does having "< >" around a pointer mean/do?"_